# ¿Cómo evitar el error "callback is not a function" en una aplicacion en Nodejs?

Tags: nodejs

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en Node. Creé un módulo llamado retangle.js, el cual exporta una funcion anonima que toma 3 parametros, uno de ellos es un callback, y estoy requiriendo dicho modulo en el index.js. Cuando llamo al modulo y le paso los 3 parametros, imprime correctamente en la primera linea de la consola el resultado deseado, Sin enbargo en las lineas siguientes en consola recibo un error que dice "callback is not a function".

Este es mi código:

**rectangle.js**

```
module.exports = (l, b, callback) => {
    if (l <= 0 || b <= 0) {
        setTimeout(() =>
            callback(new Error('No procede'), null), 2000)
    } else {
        setTimeout(() =>
            callback(null, {
                cod: "G1-04",
                cod: "G2-05"
            }), 2000);

    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const rect = require('./rectangle');

rect(a,b, (err,resp)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }else{
        console.log( ` Code 1: ${resp.cod} and Code 2: ${resp.cod}`)
    }
});

rect(0,3)
rect(3,3)
```

Acá dejo un screenshot de la consola.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien puede darme una mano para evitar que me aparezca ese mensaje de error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te falla la app porque en las últimas dos llamadas donde invocas `rect(2, 3, ...)` no estas pasando el tercer argumento que es el callback. Y dentro de `rect` tampoco validas que si hay el argumento `callback` y  cuando se ejecuta el setTimeout() pues no tiene ninguna referencia a `callback`.

Deberías invocar la función como en el primer caso o validar en rect que exista el argumento `callback`.

```
module.exports = (l, b, callback) => {
   if (!callback) {
      return; // si no hay callback no se sigue
   }
    if (l <= 0 || b <= 0) {
        setTimeout(() =>
            callback(new Error('No procede'), null), 2000)
    } else {
        setTimeout(() =>
            callback(null, {
                cod: "G1-04",
                cod: "G2-05"
            }), 2000);

    }
}

const rect = require('./rectangle');

rect(a,b, (err,resp)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }else{
        console.log( ` Code 1: ${resp.cod} and Code 2: ${resp.cod}`)
    }
});

rect(0,3)
rect(3,3)
```

Answer (score 1):

En el index.js no estas llamando bien a la función de rectangle.js.

por lo que entiendo, estas intentando crear una función intermedia para llamar a rect. Pero la estas creando mal.

La solución mas senzilla pero tendras que estar siempre enviando siempre el callback:

**Index.js**

```
const rect = require('./rectangle');

const callback = (err,resp) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }else{
        console.log( ` Code 1: ${resp.cod} and Code 2: ${resp.cod}`)
    }
};

rect(0,3, callback);
rect(3,3, callback);
```

Una solución mas compleja pero te permite siempre tener el mismo callback y no hace falta enviarlo por función:

**Index.js**

```
const rect = require('./rectangle');

const rectWithCallback = (a,b) => rect(a,b,(err,resp)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }else{
        console.log( ` Code 1: ${resp.cod} and Code 2: ${resp.cod}`)
    }
});

rectWithCallback(0,3);
rectWithCallback(3,3);
```

también podrías hacer que rect sea una función que devuelva una función. primero pidiendo el callback y después los parámetros.

**rectangle.js**

```
module.exports = callback => (l, b) => {
    if (l <= 0 || b <= 0) {
        setTimeout(
            callback(new Error('No procede'), null), 2000)
    } else {
        setTimeout(
            callback(null, {
                cod: "G1-04",
                cod: "G2-05"
            }), 2000);

    }
}
```

**index.js**

```
const rect = require('./rectangle');

const rectWithCallback = rect((err,resp)=>{
    if(err){
        console.log(err.message)
    }else{
        console.log( ` Code 1: ${resp.cod} and Code 2: ${resp.cod}`)
    }
});

rectWithCallback(0,3);
rectWithCallback(3,3);
```

Espero que te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Yo diría que de hecho no tienes una función llamada `callback`, más bien callback es la función que mandas como parametro de la función setTimeout. Según la [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) tendrías que utilizar la función de la siguiente forma:

```
setTimeout(función, tiempo, parametro1, parametro2...);
```

Es decir, que la primera vez que usas la función la tendrías que usar de la siguiente forma

```
setTimeout(() => { new Error('No procede') }, 2000, null)
```

Como puedes ver el primer parametro sería `() => { new Error('No procede') }`, esa función sería el "callback".

Me pareció ver en algunos tutoriales o manuales que a veces a la función que se manda como parametro le llaman "callback", posiblemente por ello te confundiste.